# How to create arrays from google sheet cell data?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to create an list of (4X1) arrays from google sheet data.

```
   A        B    C      D       E     F      G      H      I     J 
Project | Per1 | W1 |  Team1 | Per2 | W2 | Team2 | Per3 | W3 | Team3|
—————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————
   p1   | Bill | .5 |  Tech  | Alice|  1 | Other |      |    |      |
   p2   |Larry |  1 |  Tech  | Bill |  1 | Other | Tina | 1  | Other|
   p3   | Joe  |  2 |  Tech  | Beth |  1 | Tech  |      |    |      |
   p4   |Kathy | .5 |  Tech  |      |    |       |      |    |      |
   p5   | Bill | 1  |  Tech  | Larry|  1 | Other |      |    |      |
```

*My reputation does not allow me to post pictures

So far I am able to create a list of (3x1) arrays.

```
 function arrayOfObjects() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var vA=sh.getRange("B2:D6").getValues();
  Logger.log(vA);
}
```

So far my results are:

```
 [[Bill, 0.5, Tech], [Larry, 1.0, Other], [Joe, 2.0, Tech], [Kathy, 0.5, Other], [Alice, 1.0, Tech]]
```

But this only applies to range B2:D6

I need to be able to link names to projects (p1,p2...for further analysis)
I would like the results to be (4X1) arrays:

```
[[p1,Bill,.5,Tech], [p1,Alice,1,Other],[p2,Larry,1,Other],[p2,Bill,.5,Other],
[p2,Tina,1,Other]........[p5,Larry,1,Other]]
```

Where eventually I want a table:

```
    A           B                         
| Name | Number Of project|  
———————————————————————————
| Bill |        3         |
|Larry |        2         |
| Joe  |        1         |   
|Kathy |        1         |
| Alice|        1         |
   etc...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1x4 Arrays and Objects**

This will produce 1x4 arrays and objects as well.  Take your pick.

```
function projectInfo() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('Projects');
  var rg=sh.getDataRange();
  var vA=rg.getValues();
  var projA=[];
  var projB=[];
  for(var i=1;i<vA.length;i++) {
    for(var j=1;j<vA[i].length;j+=3) {
      if(vA[i][j] && vA[i][j+1] && vA[i][j+2]) {
        projA.push([vA[i][0],vA[i][j],vA[i][j+1],vA[i][j+2]]);
        projB.push({project:vA[i][0],person:vA[i][j],weight:vA[i][j+1],team:vA[i][j+2]}); 
      }
    }
  }
  var rObj={array:projA,object:projB};
  return rObj;
}
```

This version displays them in a little dialog and shows how you can refer to them as either indices or by name(key).

```
function projectInfo() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('Projects');
  var rg=sh.getDataRange();
  var vA=rg.getValues();
  var projA=[];
  var projB=[];
  for(var i=1;i<vA.length;i++) {
    for(var j=1;j<vA[i].length;j+=3) {
      if(vA[i][j] && vA[i][j+1] && vA[i][j+2]) {
        projA.push([vA[i][0],vA[i][j],vA[i][j+1],vA[i][j+2]]);
        projB.push({project:vA[i][0],person:vA[i][j],weight:vA[i][j+1],team:vA[i][j+2]}); 
      }
    }
  }
  var rObj={array:projA,object:projB};
  var html='<style>td,th{border:1px solid black;text-align:center;}</style><table>';
  html+='<tr><th>Project</th><th>Person</th><th>Weight</th><th>Team</th></tr>';
  html+='<tr><td colspan="4">Array(indices)</tr>';
  for(var i=0;i<projA.length;i++) {
    html+=Utilities.formatString('<tr><td>%s</td><td>%s</td><td>%s</td><td>%s</td>',projA[i][0],projA[i][1],projA[i][2],projA[i][3]);
  }
  html+='<tr><td colspan="4">Object(key,value)</tr>';
  for(var i=0;i<projB.length;i++) {
    html+=Utilities.formatString('<tr><td>%s</td><td>%s</td><td>%s</td><td>%s</td>',projB[i].project,projB[i].person,projB[i].weight,projB[i].team);
  }
  html+='</table>';
  var userInterface=HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(userInterface, 'Array on Top and Object on Bottom')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So you need to go row by row and make an entry for each person on the team?

```
data = vA; 
for (var i=0; i<data.length;i++)
    {
    var project = data[i][0];
    if (data[i][1]!="")push([project,data[i][1],data[i][2],data[i][3] ]);//first person
    if (data[i][4]!="")push([project,data[i][4],data[i][5],data[i][6] ]);//second person
    if (data[i][7]!="")push([project,data[i][7],data[i][8],data[i][9] ]);//third person
    }//for loop
```

There is probably a more elegant way to do it but this is what I'd do first.